# trim() check doesn't work and app crashes - Android

Tags: android, methods, crash, trim

I tried this code (relevant parts..):

```
    private EditText weightEditText,heightEditText;

    weightEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightEditText); 
    heightEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightEditText);

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.clear: clearFields();toastClearingMessage(); break;
        case R.id.goButton: runGoButton(); break;
        }//switch
    }

    private void runGoButton() {
        if (heightWeightFieldsValuesGood() && heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty() )
            runCalculations();
        else
            toastMessageReEnterValues();
    }

    private boolean heightWeightFieldsValuesGood() {
        if (getWeight()>0 && getHeight()>0)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    private boolean heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty(){
        if ( (weightEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) || (heightEditText.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) )
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    private float getHeight() {
        return Float.parseFloat(heightEditText.getText().toString());
    }

    private float getWeight() {
        return Float.parseFloat(weightEditText.getText().toString());
    }
```

Crash Log:

```
10-08 01:21:54.260: W/dalvikvm(8172): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172): java.lang.NumberFormatException: 
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.util.FloatingPointParser.parseFloat(FloatingPointParser.java:305)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:291)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at com.example.bmi.calculator.MainPage.getWeight(MainPage.java:122)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at com.example.bmi.calculator.MainPage.heightWeightFieldsValuesGood(MainPage.java:75)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at com.example.bmi.calculator.MainPage.runGoButton(MainPage.java:63)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at com.example.bmi.calculator.MainPage.onClick(MainPage.java:58)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2420)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8941)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-08 01:21:54.260: E/AndroidRuntime(8172):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Everything runs just fine, BUT if I clicked the GO button without insert any fields values, the program just crash and close... and that although I'm using the trim() method...

By the way, if I enter zero value to both fields, it works fine (the appropriate Toast message)
Any ideas ?... 
Thanks ! :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably simplify some code with the use of [TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html).

```
private boolean heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty(){
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(weightEditText.getText()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(heightEditText.getText() )) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
 }
```

and then in your `runGoButton()` method:

```
private void runGoButton() {
        // Reverse these since you need to check for empty first.
        if (heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty() && heightWeightFieldsValuesGood())
            runCalculations();
        else
            toastMessageReEnterValues();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are using toString() wrong, you should call it on editText's getText() method, and not on the edit text itself

also, you should do compare to "", and not to ' '

the trim() is uneccesary in this case

should be like this:

weightEditText.getText().toString().equals("") ...

<<<<<< EDIT >>>>>>>>

```
   private boolean heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty(){
    if ( (weightEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) || (heightEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) )
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

<<<<<<< EDIT 2 >>>>>>>>>

```
    if (heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty() && heightWeightFieldsValuesGood())


  private float getHeight(){
        Float from_value;
        try{
            from_value = Float.parseFloat(heightEditText.getText().toString());
        } catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            from_value = 0.0f;
        }

        return from_value;
    }
```

Comment: I edit my question with my getters, can you please write down the fixed heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty() method I should use?

Comment: @Adam see the edit.  If it still crashes, you have other problem, and you'll need to post the crash log

Comment: I changed it but now I'm using toString twice, on the getters and on the heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty().. still crashes

Comment: @Adam mark the first line, then with Shift+Left Click mark the last line, copy it (Ctrl + C) and past (Ctrl + V) here

Comment: @Adam see the next edit, you should first check for empty text, and then check for good values. also wrap the getters with try and cache for preventing another unexpected crashes

Comment: @Adam : the problem is not with the trim() function , the problem is you tried to parse a string which is not a valid float , so you should catch the NumberFormatException by using try catch on your method of parse

Comment: works !! thx .. what try catch does in that case ?
I hardly remember that try-catch usually gives a user custom error or something isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

an empty string, if trimmed, will not equal a string containing a space character - remove the space from the two *equals* checks

Also, you should check the fields are not empty before trying to convert the values to numbers.  ie your check should be:

```
if (heightWeightFieldsNotEmpty() && heightWeightFieldsValuesGood())
```

Note: I also stripped out the extranous *==true* as they aren't needed for correctness, and they added nothing to the legibitility of the code.  By putting the 'notEmpty' test first, if it fails the code will not attempt to run the 'valuesGood' test, thus avoiding a numeric test against the empty strings

Comment: as per my updated answer, the code was probably failing before it got to the empty test, because you were first attempting to do a numeric test on the fields

Comment: quote: 'I also stripped out the extraneous ==true': I know :-) a moment of desperation.... but neither both ways it's not working...

Comment: As it happens, I suspect that rrowland and dor506 have identified why the trim check always failed - because you're getting a reference to the object, and not the actual value, the string will always contain text.  I think that, between all the answers, we've probably identified the problem... :p